# Nested Function Call in Python

Tags: python, function, automation

I'm working on an project where I have defined a lot of functions in my code. I just have a doubt, if it is possible to put all these functions inside a single function and just call this single function in main.

```
class Project:
    def login(self):
        #code
    def upload(self):
        #code
    def import(self):
        #code

if __name__ == '__main__':
    c=Project()
    c.login()
    c.upload()
    c.import()
```

So, my doubt is , is it possible to include all the methods inside a single method and call only one method in the main which triggers all the methods. Thanks!

Comment: You can certainly do that. However, Andrew's approach is lot cleaner if you have too many of these functions.

Comment: Yep i will try !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
class Project:
    def login(self):
        #code
    def upload(self):
        #code
    def import(self):
        #code
    def do_all(self):
        self.login()
        self.upload()
        self.import()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    c=Project()
    c.do_all()
```

Comment: Since you have only methods on your class, you might consider simply defining the functions at the module level. Then you can call do_all() without instantiating an object.